# Samsung Gear S3 music sync

Tags: sync, music

I mainly use my Gear S3 for listening music while running or doing exercises in gym. But It is very annoying to add new songs into it. First I have to download new songs to my computer, then I have to transfer downloaded songs to my android phone and then to my Gear S3.

Is there any solutions to make it easier. Best case scenario would be that, I have one folder in my PC and if I add song into there or delete songs, it will sync automatically to gear s3 as well. Maybe it is somehow possible to sync folder in PC to the android and from android to gear s3.

Hope that someone have had similar wish and have found solution.